# JHipster Registry on Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring-boot, registry, jhipster, cloud-foundry, netflix-eureka

I am having issues getting the jhipster registry to work with cloud foundry. Here's what I am trying to do
I deployed Jhipster registry to cloudfoundry. I see the Jhipster Registry app running fine. I can see the app dashboard in my browser.
Now I have a microservice app created on my machine. I try to connect to the Jhipster from the microservice app running on my machine.

eureka configuration in my application-dev.yml

```
eureka:
instance:
    hostname: jhipsterregistry.run.asv-pr.ice.predix.io
    prefer-ip-address: true
    nonSecurePortEnabled: false
    securePortEnabled: true
client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    service-url:
        defaultZone: https://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipsterregistry.run.asv-pr.ice.predix.io/eureka/
```

Configuration in my bootstrap.yml file

```
spring:
application:
    name: AttendanceDBService
profiles:
    # The commented value for `active` can be replaced with valid Spring profiles to load.
    # Otherwise, it will be filled in by maven when building the WAR file
    # Either way, it can be overridden by `--spring.profiles.active` value passed in the commandline or `-Dspring.profiles.active` set in `JAVA_OPTS`
    active: #spring.profiles.active#
cloud:
    config:
        fail-fast: false # if not in "prod" profile, do not force to use Spring Cloud Config
        uri: https://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipsterregistry.run.asv-pr.ice.predix.io/config
```

I get below error ...

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.UnknownHostException: jhipsterregistry.run.asv-pr.ice.predix.io
at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123)
at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:194)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:165)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:119)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1013)
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:927)
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:408)
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:266)
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:262)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:60)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:225)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b26bcab7.CGLIB$eurekaClient$1(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b26bcab7$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5814431.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b26bcab7.eurekaClient(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:345)
at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:359)
at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:176)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getTargetObject(EurekaRegistration.java:133)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient(EurekaRegistration.java:122)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:56)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:37)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:73)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:175)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:50)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:348)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:151)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:114)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
at com.ge.pwr.sps.bf.mms.attendancedbservice.AttendanceDbServiceApp.main(AttendanceDbServiceApp.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: jhipsterregistry.run.asv-pr.ice.predix.io
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:907)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1302)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1255)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1171)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1105)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:263)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173)
... 72 common frames omitted
```

2018-03-13 22:56:27.440  WARN 17584 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: java.net.UnknownHostException: jhipsterregistry.run.asv-pr.ice.predix.io
2018-03-13 22:56:27.441 ERROR 17584 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_ATTENDANCEDBSERVICE/AttendanceDBService:b5c57f1f0207b7e1acd513b1b2df415d - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1013)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:927)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.(DiscoveryClient.java:408)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.(DiscoveryClient.java:266)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.(DiscoveryClient.java:262)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.(CloudEurekaClient.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:225)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b26bcab7.CGLIB$eurekaClient$1()
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b26bcab7$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5814431.invoke()
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b26bcab7.eurekaClient()
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:345)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:359)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:176)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getTargetObject(EurekaRegistration.java:133)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient(EurekaRegistration.java:122)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:56)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:37)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:73)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:175)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:348)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:114)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at com.ge.pwr.sps.bf.mms.attendancedbservice.AttendanceDbServiceApp.main(AttendanceDbServiceApp.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm, as you are getting an UnknownHostException, the deployed JHipster Registry doesn't seem to be reachable.I am also not able to access http://jhipsterregistry.run.asv-pr.ice.predix.io/ via my browser. Should it be available on the internet? If yes, you should check in CF again, whether it is running. Via `cf apps` you can also see on which URL the application should be accessible. Can you still access the deployed registry from your workstation?

Comment: Thanks for your response Stefan. jhipsterregistry.run.asv-pr.ice.predix.io is accessible only within my organization network. That's the reason you are not able to access it. It works for me in my browser. I see the dashboard and all the menu options.

Comment: anybody can help on this?